# При деплое через deploy.sh возникает ошибка

Tags: linux, ruby, развертывание

Добрый день. Помогите пожалуйста с проблемкой. Есть скрипт деплоя проэкта на Ruby.

```
#!/bin/sh


if [ $# -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "Usage:"
    echo "  ./deploy.sh some_stage_name"
else
    rvm use `cat .ruby-version`@`if [ -f .ruby-gemset ]; then cat .ruby-gemset; fi;` do bundle exec cap $@ deploy &&
    cd ./legacy &&
    rvm use `cat .ruby-version`@`if [ -f .ruby-gemset ]; then cat .ruby-gemset; fi;` do bundle exec cap $@ deploy &&
    cd ..
fi;
```

Если я его запускаю через cap servername deploy всё отрабатывает нормально. А если `./deploy.sh servername` то получаю ошибку.

```
The deploy has failed with an error: #<SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError: Exception while executing on host 1.2.3.4: "\xE2" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8
```

Эта ошибка выпадет только на одном сервере, и только при запуске ./deploy.sh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема была в bundle файле, там были коменты на русском. Как только это нашел всё стало ясно.

Answer (score 1):

Рекомендую воспользоваться capistrano для деплоя rails приложений (и не только)

http://capistranorb.com/